# Compiling libpng 1.6.14 fails

Tags: compiling

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux based systems. I need to compile libpng 1.6.14 to analyze one of its binaries.
I am running:

```
tar -xvf libpng-1.6.14.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.6.14
sudo bash configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng   //is running fine without errors
sudo make install
```

This is what I get:

[image: error 2, many things not found]

I found a similar problem [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114431/libtool-fails-while-attempting-to-compile-gmp)

I tried to manipulate the "libtool" file but without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello. Your question is missing the most basic info. What version of Ubuntu are you using? I do not see a clearly stated question. From your question <Tried to manipulate the "libtool" file but without success,> What does this mean?

Comment: Yes, my apologize. Im using 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Yes @David, my apologize. Im using 20.04.4 LTS. "Manipulated" like in the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114431/libtool-fails-while-attempting-to-compile-gmp] described, this means, I have replaced in "libtool" line 2447 ' base_compile+=" $lastarg " ' with ' base_compile="$base_compile $lastarg" ' (not sure if this is the correct syntax). My question is, what do I need to do to compile this lib successful

Comment: @steeldriver, compiler are installed. I ran the provided commands once more to confirm, same outcome as well when running only 'make'

Comment: OK so can you provide a link to the source you downloaded? That way, we can attempt to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @steeldriver, sure its libpng-1.6.14.tar.xz: [https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/older-releases/1.6.14/]

Comment: or from here: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16BzdYP4L3Gq6ZBdZJBSHF0Bf6zSPwFoo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the problem does seem to be because the provided `./libtool` is a bash script,

```
$ file ./libtool
./libtool: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

but `make` defaults to executing it with `/bin/sh`, which in Ubuntu is symlinked to the `dash` shell by default:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  4 10:27 /bin/sh -> dash
```

and `dash` does not support the non-POSIX string concatenation `+=`:

```
$ dash -c 'foo+=bar'
dash: 1: foo+=bar: not found
```

This is indeed the same issue discussed in the link you provided, in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117577)

There are many ways to tackle this - IMHO the cleanest is to tell the configure script to override the Makefile's default `SHELL` variable:

```
./configure SHELL=/bin/bash --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
make
sudo make install
```

(I suggest you start over with a clean install i.e. delete the libpng-1.6.14 directory and unpack the archive again.)

Comment: thank you very much for all steps and explanations!